# MySql Database Replication from local to remote

Tags: mysql, replication

We have a web application running on local machine. And we would like to replicate the MySQL database to remote (web). I have looked at the tutorials online for that and I have one concern about the MASTER HOST ADDRESS. Since we usually shut down the laptops at the end of the day, the IP address will not be the same everyday. Is there any other way or method that replication can be achieved without specifying the IP from local to remote?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL replication is pretty robust and will handle correctly situations where the master server is offline for prolonged periods of time.

your laptop could establish a VPN tunnel to the replica server or some relay server. private addressing that you'd use on both endpoints of the tunnel would be static. this approach will work fine regardless of type of internet connection used - one day it could be at home, another day at the office, another day using WiFi hotspot at a cafeteria.

[Wireguard](https://www.wireguard.com/), [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/) would likely be easier to set up and troubleshoot, IPSec is another alternative.

things worth keeping in mind:

- have long enough binlog retention period on the database master side - so the past transactions have chance to replicate to the slave. it's set by [expire_log_days](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_expire_logs_days).
- set infinite [master-retry-count](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-replica.html#option_mysqld_master-retry-count)